# Javascript compare not working

Tags: javascript, compare, alert

I have a condition in javascript like below

```
function check()
{
    var amount = document.getElementById('pamount').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var pmin = document.getElementById('pmin').value;
    var pmax = document.getElementById('pmax').value;
    var stock = document.getElementById('stocks').value;

    if (amount > pmax) {
        alert('Price should not be more than maximum price');
        return false;
    }
    if (amount < pmin) {
        alert('Price should not be less than minimum price');
        return false;
    }
    if (quantity > stock) {
        alert('Please enter quantity no more than maximum');
        return false;
    }
    if (quantity < 1) {
        alert('Please enter valid quantity');
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the html fields

```
<input type="text" value=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="form-control small qty_box" id="qty" name="qty">
<input style="width:90px; float:left" type="text" value="" class="form-control small" id="pmin" name="min">
<input style="width:90px; float:left" type="text" class="form-control small" id="pmax" name="max">
```

But it always return false. When I enter less value for amount it alerts the same. I tried alerting amount and pmax. It gets actual value. But something wrong with this compare
I gave amount as 75 and pmax as 100.

Comment: Please show full code.

Comment: @user3280126 But I tried alerting values. It shows actual values only

Comment: Which alert are you getting? How about `quantity`, `stock` and `pmin`?

Comment: Add the HTML you're referencing to the question.

Comment: @joelcj, does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/PH7Ww/?

Comment: @Andy no it shows same error. Did you check?

Comment: [How about now?](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/PH7Ww/)

Comment: No. I gave min=50, max=100, amt=75. But it alerts "Price should not be more than maximum price"

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat() or parseInt() as per your need to compare numbers. Below code used parseFloat().

```
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pamount').value);
    var quantity = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value));
    var pmin = parseFloat(parseFloat(document.getElementById('pmin').value);
    var pmax = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pmax').value);
    var stock = parseFloat(document.getElementById('stocks').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code. Check whether your browser is disabled the javascript. That will be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that return false from { }

`if (amount > pmax) {
        alert('Price should not be more than maximum price');
         }
       else 
  //rest of the code`

Comment: This is not a solution for this. It doesn't work dude :(